# Live search MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm looking for live search for ASP.NET and entity framework. I'm a little bit green with it. I read that it needs to use ajax, but I never used it before and can't get good example. Here is a piece of code, cshtml (part of textbox)

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        <h4>Search for a client: </h4>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Name">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBox("Name", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name" })
        </div>
        <div><h6></h6></div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Surname">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            @Html.TextBox("Surname", "", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Surname" })
        </div>
        <div><h6></h6></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal">Search</button>
    </div>
```

this is a part of controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string Name, string Surname)
    {
        var SearchList = from m in db.Klienci
                         select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
        {
            SearchList = SearchList.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(Name));
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname))
        {
            SearchList = SearchList.Where(s => s.Nazwisko.Contains(Surname));
        }
        return View(SearchList);
    }
```

So it search for me clients by name and surname, but it refresh full page when it lost focus or after clicking the button. How to solve it, to get live search? after each keystroke search through database? I'm a little bit green, would you Help me?

Comment: where is the relevant javascript code ?

Comment: there are bootstrap's classes

Comment: search is done with http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `keyup` event on your input element, read the value and send it to the server using ajax. Return the results and in the ajax call's success callback, update the ui with the results.

```
$(function() {

    $("#Name,#SurName").keyup(function(e) {
            var n = $("#Name").val();
            var sn = $("#SurName").val();
            $.get("/Home/Index?Name="+n+"&SurName="+sn,function(r){
               //update ui with results
               $("#resultsTable").html(r);
            });

    });

});
```

The code basically listens to the key up event on the two input textboxes and read the values and send to the `/Home/Index` action method using jquery get method asynchronously.When the action method returns the response, we update the DOM.

Assuming `resultsTable` is the Id of the table where we list the results.

Also, since you are returning the partial view result ( without layout headers), you should use `return PartialView()` instead of `return View()`

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView(SearchList);

return View(SearchList);
```

Comment: Somehow it does not read an input from the textboxes, when I change `var n = $("#Name").val();` to `n = "sth"` it filter the table by the "sth" string

Comment: Check the view source of your page and make sure that your input field's id is `Name`

Comment: the view source is exactly the same as in the question, but I made another view (Search)which is only the table so I can use `PartialView()` there. I changed the `"/Home/Index?Name="` to `"/Home/Search?Name="`

Comment: but I'm sure that it detects that I stroke key by `$("#Name, #Surname").keyup(function (e)`, what make me confusing

Comment: Found the issue. The Id of texboxes was the same as function inputs what causes this freaky error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is nice example/tutorial how to use Ajax with ASP.NET MVC

http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html

**EDITED: 2016-07-20**

Example:

```js
 $(function () {
        $("searchField").keyup(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Controller/Action",
                data: data,
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to visit the server to get data from server and without ajax it is not possible. Now the question is how to make ajax call, you can use jQuery js lib to do but I would recommend you to try angular as data binding in angular will fulfill your needs.
Take a look at followings links
 [Angular Ajax Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) -
[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)